# Is it possible to enable non-arc files without adding "fno-objc-arc" in compile sources of Build Phases?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Is it possible to somehow handle the non-arc files without adding `fno-objc-arc` to the compile sources in the build phases? More specifically, is there any way to add `fno-objc-arc` somewhere in the code? The reason is, I want to open source one of my library which uses non-arc files and I don't want people who use my library to manually add `fno-objc-arc`. Just drag and drop...

Comment: it is a compiler-flag, not a runtime-flag, therefore you can set it in the compiler only, not in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. But if you look at what some libraries do, they write macros that will conditionally call the MRC calls, e.g., `release`, `autorelease`, etc., depending upon whether the user is compiling with ARC or not, e.g. using the `__has_feature(objc_arc)` test. The code then uses these macros, rather than the standard `release`, `retain`, `autorelease` calls. With careful implementation, you can then have a single codebase support both ARC and MRC.

For example, look at [`FMDatabase.h`](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.h) of the FMDB library. Effectively, you replace your MRC calls with these macros, and they'll only be conditionally included, depending upon whether the project is using ARC or not.

```
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
    #define FMDBAutorelease(__v) ([__v autorelease]);
    #define FMDBReturnAutoreleased FMDBAutorelease

    #define FMDBRetain(__v) ([__v retain]);
    #define FMDBReturnRetained FMDBRetain

    #define FMDBRelease(__v) ([__v release]);
#else
    // -fobjc-arc
    #define FMDBAutorelease(__v)
    #define FMDBReturnAutoreleased(__v) (__v)

    #define FMDBRetain(__v)
    #define FMDBReturnRetained(__v) (__v)

    #define FMDBRelease(__v)
#endif
```