# Writing library code to support both ARC and MRR

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working on a library and I would like to support both memory management approaches (ARC and MRR) in one codebase.

I don't want to force users to use special flags for my code (-fobjc-arc).

I know about the preprocessor test: `#if __has_feature(objc_arc)`, but what is the best practice to use that to cover the all differences?

Does anyone have any experience with that to make it clean and easy to work with?

The preferable way would be to use some macros for translations between ARC and non-ARC, which I can use in my code.

=========

My problem was solved by the accepted answer, but as a tip for others, I found [a blog post by John Blanco](http://raptureinvenice.com/arc-support-without-branches/) giving the best set of examples for how to handle my problem.

Comment: How are you going to distribute your library? If you are just going to distribute a .framework or static library, it doesn't matter, just develop it with ARC and people without ARC can use it.

Comment: It will be more company library for several projects (some are ARC some not). For simplicity I wanted to distribute it as code not .framework, but if making .framework solves a problem - maybe I will do it this way

Comment: Note that you can add the flag -fobjc-arc or -fobjc-no-arc to enable/disable ARC on a file-by-file basis. So it's fairly easy to mix ARC and non-ARC code in the same project. See:  http://www.codeography.com/2011/10/10/making-arc-and-non-arc-play-nice.html

Comment: I know - as wrote in a question I would like to avoid that and put responsibility for handling both on my own code :)

Comment: You can use the macro to write code that has -release calls for non-arc, but developing & maintaining it will be a nightmare.

Comment: This should answer your question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076505/is-it-possible-to-enable-non-arc-files-without-adding-fno-objc-arc-in-compile

Comment: If you listen to anyone, listen to bbum...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer the code of [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) in github. I think, that's what you want.

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#define MB_AUTORELEASE(exp) exp
#define MB_RELEASE(exp) exp
#define MB_RETAIN(exp) exp
#else
#define MB_AUTORELEASE(exp) [exp autorelease]
#define MB_RELEASE(exp) [exp release]
#define MB_RETAIN(exp) [exp retain]
#endif
```

This is how they are using these macros

```
self.indicator = MB_AUTORELEASE([[MBRoundProgressView alloc] init]);
```

Comment: Ok - that one sounds reasonable. I will have to define a set on conversions however for that which I should handle :) Was hoping for a list of those to be ohnest ;] Anyways that is closest answer for what I wanted to do. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem, to take into account [super dealloc] which must be called in -dealloc overrides when ARC is disabled, and is illegal when ARC is enabled. Again, this is a bad idea...

Answer (score 4):

Either use ARC and instruct people who will use the code to set compilation flags per file (`-fobjc-arc`), and force them to do so by adding this to the header:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
  #error ARC must be enabled!
#endif
```

Or build as lib/framework with ARC enabled. 
Wrapping memory management code in preprocessor directives is a terrible idea.

Comment: As described in question - I prefer to make code which supports both options at once - instead of using this flag. But thanks.

Comment: @Suresh linked to MBProgressHUD which does that. I also found few more libraries that are handling that correctly. For me it makes perfect sense to prepare a code that works in all environments :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to support both ARC and Non-ARC code is to go to the Target, Build Phases, and to the Compile Sources section.

From there you should see all your .m files. You can then add to any file **-fno-objc-arc** under the Compiler Flags to tell the compiler to ignore ARC.

Comment: I know this one and as described in my question - I don't want this approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, don't do this.   You'll end up having to test your code fully twice for every change.   And debugging everything twice.   It isn't worth the effort.

You really *really* want to write your code purely ARC or purely non-ARC.

There are very few constructs that can appear in a header file that won't work in one or the other.